# When is Laylatul-Qadr? (Shia view)

Tags: shiism, laylat-al-qadr

I am aware that there could be few days as foreseen days to be Laylatul-Qadr or the night of decree (such as 19, 21, 23, and 27 of Ramadan), but I wonder which day is right? (According to Shia's viewpoint)

Answer (score 7):

In accordance with the view of Shia scholars (majority of them), **the night of decree (Laylatul-Qadr لیله القدر)** probably is one of the following days of Ramadan :

- **19th**
- **21st**
- **23rd**

---

Imam Aboo Ja’far Muhammad ebn Ali-al-Baqir (a.s.) is quoted in Bihar al-Anwar and Da’aim al-Islam as mentioned:

> "The 17th night of the month of Ramadhan is when the 2 parties met,
>
> and the 19th is at the time that the lists of the pilgrims is written
> down,
>
> and the 21st is at the time that successors to the Prophets passed
> away and Jesus Christ (as)  was raised to heaven and Moses (as) passed
> away,
>
> whereas the 23rd is hoped to be Lailatul-Qadr."

---

Or according to another narration: Al-Husayn ibn ‘Ubaydullah, in accordance with Majalis al-Shaykh, as quoted on p. 2, Vol. 94, of Bihar al-Anwar, quotes Ahmad ibn Mohammad ibn Yahya who in turn quotes his father saying:

> "I was in the company of Abu Abdullah (as) when Abu Busayr inquired
> him, ‘Which night is the one when one is to plead to his Lord whatever
> he wishes to plead?' The Imam (as) answered him by saying, ‘Either the
> twenty-first or the twenty-third."
>
> According to Aboo Abdullah (as), as he likewise quoted in the same
> volume of Bihar al-Anwar mentioned:  "The 23rd night of Ramadhan (the
> month of Ramadhan) is the one at the time that every weighty issue is
> decided, at the time that trials, tribulations, deaths, and means of
> sustenance and other issues which are determined, and so will whatever
> God decrees to happen for the whole next year; well, congratulations
> to anyone who remains awake during it bowing, prostrating,
> contemplating upon his sins, weeping on their account, for if you do
> all of that, Allah willing, you will never be disappointed."

---

**As a result, according to the narrations above, we can say that the 23rd of Ramadhan is more likely to be Laylatul Qadr.**

---

Source(s):

- [www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/fast-month-ramadhan-philosophy-and-ahkam-yasin-t-al-jibouri/which-night-lailatul-qadr)
- [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread7366.html)

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulillah All praise is due to Allah, who is kind to all in this physical world.

As a Student I wanna say that according to me I have read from many books like as Bihar ul Anwar, Mufatih ul Jinan etc. that the Lailat ul Qadr is on 23th of Ramadan......

Shab-e-Qadr [Lailat-ul-Qadr — the Night Of Power] — the Qur’anIn the name of God, the Lord of Grace, the Most MercifulFrom on high have We bestowed it (i.e. the Qur’an) on the Night of Power. Would that you knew what the Night of Power is! The Night of Power is better than a thousand months. On that night the angels and the Spirit by their Lord’s leave descend with all His decrees. That night is peace, till the break of dawn.[Power “Al-Qadr” 97: 1 – 5]